# shifting all child divs inside a parent div when a child div is destroyed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created this jsbin : http://jsbin.com/qoriqihapara/1/edit

as you can see i have two problems i don't know how to solve

1. if you opened the first chat window then the second and you close the first,then open again the first ,you see the two chat windows are overlapped and that because the calculation of `right` is not perfect
2. when closing a chat window that is not the first or the last ( considering having multiple chat window opened ), is there any method wish can shift all the chat window to the right ???

code :

```
var right = 10;
var rightPadding = 10;
function CreateDiv(id)
{
 var ToAppend = "<div class='Msg_container_dv' id='Msg_container_dv_" + id + "' style='right:" + right + "px' >"
                       + "<div class='Chat_Header_dv'>"
                       + "<table><tr>"
                       + "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='closeChatwnd(\"Msg_container_dv_" + id + "\")' >close window</a></td>"
                       + "</tr></table>"
                       + "</div>"
                       + "<div class='Chat_Body_Container' id='Chat_Body_Container_" + id + "'>" + id + "...</div>"
                       + "<div class='Chat_Footer_Container'>text here...</div>"
                       + "</div>";
right = right + (280 + rightPadding); // 280 is the width of the chat window
$("#chat_div_container").append(ToAppend);

}
function closeChatwnd(id)
{
 $("#" + id).remove();
 right = right - (280 + rightPadding);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to do like this:

```
#chat_div_container
{
  padding-right:15px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  right:0px;
  width:200%; /*or more*/
}
```

and for `Msg_container_dv`

```
.Msg_container_dv
{
  height:280px;
  width:280px;
  border:1px solid #868686;
  bottom:0px;
  float:right;
}
```

Simple and easy.

Don't forget to remove `style='right:" + right + "px'` from  `Msg_container_dv`

Comment: I also like this solution which was nearly the same like the one in my pen (rejected) but ***BE AWARE*** if the user opens too many chat windows its going to be ugly but should not be too complicated to fix this...